# How display photo under the text?

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have to display random photo using array and rand function.

Now I would add text under each photo(For example, the words of the elders text with image)

my code:

```
<?php


$images=array(
    array('file'=>'pic1','alt'=>"Your Description About pic1"),
    array('file'=>'pic2','alt'=>"Your Description About pic2"),
    array('file'=>'pic3','alt'=>"Your Description About pic3"),
    array('file'=>'pic4','alt'=>"Your Description About pic4"),
    array('file'=>'pic5','alt'=>"Your Description About pic5"),
    array('file'=>'pic6','alt'=>"Your Description About pic6"),
    )
    $i=rand(0,count($images)-1);
    $selectimage="newfolder/{$images[$i]['file']}.jpg";
    $alt=$images[$i]['alt'];

 if (file_exists($selectimage) && is_readable($selectimage))

    $imagesize= getimagesize($selectimage);
?>
```

view in htm

```
<img src="<?php echo $selectimage;?> "  alt="<?php echo $alt ; ?>" <?php echo $imagesize[3] ; ?> />
```

What do I do?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I can not display text under the photos   //////// random pic with text

Comment: you dont actully have code displaying an image either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found.

for display text should  add text to array.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <?php 

  $images= array(
array('file' => 'pic1' ,'txt'=>'sample1', 'alt' => "Your Discription About pic1"),
array('file' => 'pic2','txt'=>'sample2' , 'alt '=> "Your Discription About pic2"),
array('file'=> 'pic3' ,'txt'=>'sample3', 'alt'  => "Your Discription About pic3"),
array('file' => 'pic4','txt'=>'sample4' , 'alt' => "Your Discription About pic4"),
array('file'=>'pic5','txt'=>'sample5' , 'alt'  => "Your Discription About pic5")
);

$i=rand(0,count($images)-1);
$selectimage="newfolder/{$images[$i]['file']}.jpg";
$alt=$images[$i]['alt'];
if (file_exists($selectimage) && is_readable($selectimage)) {
$imagesize= getimagesize($selectimage);
}

?>
</head>
<body>
<img src="<?php echo $selectimage;?> " />
<?php echo $images[$i]['txt'];?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I know of is to wrap the image and text then position accordingly.

```
<?php

   $images = array(
     array('file'=>'pic1','alt'=>"Your Description About pic1", 'text'=>"Pic1 Subtext"),
     array('file'=>'pic2','alt'=>"Your Description About pic2", 'text'=>"Pic1 Subtext")
     );

   $i=rand(0,count($images)-1);
   $selectimage="newfolder/{$images[$i]['file']}.jpg";
   $alt=$images[$i]['alt'];
   $subtitle = $images[$i]['text'];


   if (file_exists($selectimage) && is_readable($selectimage)) {
     $imagesize= getimagesize($selectimage);    
   }

?>

<div class="image_wrapper">
   <img src="<?= $selectimage; ?>" alt="<?= $alt; ?>"/>
   <p class="img_subtitle"><?= $subtitle; ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a nice idea.but id don't have display alt photo.//I have display For example, the words of the elders text's with photo

Comment: using getimagesize()'s third parameter in a style tag won't work since the output is for inside the img tag like this: `height="yyy" width="xxx"`

Comment: @Mortzea Sorry, I read better when not stuffed with lunch.  :)  But you could put whatever text in you want.   If you want to group a photo with a text, I'd wrap it in a div.  Maybe add another field in the array that contains the text you want for each photo.

Comment: can you Bring the example?

Comment: I edited the example above.   Is this what you were talking about?

Answer (score 1):

you have syntax error in your code. you need to use `,` instead of `;` in array and use `;` at the end of each statement.

```
$images=array(
    array('file'=>'pic1','alt'=>"Your Description About pic1"),
    array('file'=>'pic2','alt'=>"Your Description About pic2"),
    array('file'=>'pic3','alt'=>"Your Description About pic3"),
    array('file'=>'pic4','alt'=>"Your Description About pic4"),
    array('file'=>'pic5','alt'=>"Your Description About pic5"),
    array('file'=>'pic6','alt'=>"Your Description About pic6")
    );
```